# CSS display: flex pushing children up beyond parent's top

Tags: html, css

I want a container class that will arrange children from left to right and from top to bottom.

I don't want my container to spill outside of the parent's inner box.

If children take up more space than that I want a vertical scroll bar so that I can see all the children if I want to.

I defined `.wrap-container` like so:

```css
.wrap-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center; // vertically
  align-items: flex-start; // horizontally
  // justify-content: space-between; /* Space items evenly along the main axis */
  padding: 15px;
  gap: 15px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: solid blue 1px;
  // height: calc(100% - 30px);
  // width: calc(100% - 30px);
  max-height: calc(100% - 30px); 
  max-width: calc(100% - 30px);
  overflow: auto;
}
```

It arranges them correctly, but it does not handle the overflow as it should. I can never see the top of the first row of children.

To clarify, I know `display: flex` is allowed to spill outside of the parent, hence

```css
max-height: calc(100% - 30px); 
max-width: calc(100% - 30px);
```

The `30px` is to account for the parent's padding.
Which, by the way, seems like a bug as well - you would think that specifying `max-height: 100%` should do it, but no, you need to know how the parent is defined, which seems wrong.

But in any case, even if I arrange `.wrap-container` to not spill outside of its parent, it still does not handle the children correctly.
Please see what I mean here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-gwqxpg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss

The parent of `.wrap-container` is defined like so:

```css
.parent {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid red 1px;
  padding: 15px;
  gap: 15px;
  margin: 70px;
}
```

and children of `.wrap-container` like so:

```css
.child {
  border: 1px solid transparent; 
  border-image-slice: 1; 
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
  padding: 5px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

It then looks like this:

[image]

Even scrolled all the way up you can't see "It's working 1" or "It's working 2".

Comment: Just for your information: `//`  is not a valid way to do comments in CSS. This will lead to problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the 'align-content: center;' from '.wrap-container'
Setting 'align-content: start' will also work.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why? According to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-content it should have helped but it broke it???

Comment: I'm also learning myself so not sure, but since the container has the 'max-height' value and 'align-content' it must be displaying the content in the center. I'm sure it would also work if you set the 'align-content' to 'start'.